Возможно ли такое согласование: "ни одной из вариаций, сплетавшей бы..."?

Так вот, чего не было (а речь идёт о 1977—1979 годах): ни меня, ни
моих трёх товарок, ни "Московского церковного вестника", ни "Церковных
ведомостей", ни одной из вариаций, сплетавшей бы
"московский-вестник-ведомости". Газеты не существовало. А существовал
"Журнал Московской Патриархии" - ну не левачила я в журнале!

